# Relative clause to say object of an object

Tags: relative-clauses

I'm confused because I don't know the differences between which and that when I talk about object of an object. Furthermore, I don't know how to use the relative clause correctly when I talk about object of an object. Is this sentence correct?
- The house that/which TV was damaged in the fire is now fixed.

Comment: You can Google "relative pronoun" and read them. Your question is too broad and too basic for this community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use *whose*. *Whose* can be essential or not, depending on whether the information is important. It is used for both people and things, even though it sounds a bit weird when it isn't referring to people. Trust me, it's OK to use it for things.

The house, whose TV was damaged in the fire, is now fixed.

Or

The house whose TV was damaged in the fire is now fixed.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't really make sense to say that the house is fixed if it was the TV that was damaged in a fire.

Comment: The TV being damaged in the fire and the house being fixed don't have to be related. The fire could have happened years ago and the house could have been damaged recently. In the first example, I'm just telling you some extra information, but you know which house I'm talking about. In the second example, I'm helping to identify which house has been fixed, because if I didn't, you wouldn't know which house I'm talking about.

Comment: The thing is, if I read that sentence I'd strongly suspect that it was misworded, since it's simply not a logical relationship.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. When reading that, it's odd to see that the house is the thing being fixed if the TV is the thing that is damaged. I was just using the example provided by Viettungvuong.

Comment: @Rathony - I have no dispute with your close vote; I just think your comment to Zachary could have been a bit more helpful had it been phrased more constructively.